WPF Adorner MouseOver
I have created an adorner which it to be applied to a Textbox and this is for our custom built Spell-Checking.
Whenever there is an Unknown Word, the adorner will add an underline using drawingcontext.drawline. Here is the code:
    _highlighterPen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), 2)
    {
        EndLineCap = PenLineCap.Square,
        StartLineCap = PenLineCap.Square
    };

    private void HighlightWord(DrawingContext drawingContext, int characterIndex, int wordLength)
    {
        if (characterIndex + wordLength > _textbox.Text.Length)
            return;

        var start = _textbox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(characterIndex);
        var end = _textbox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(characterIndex + (wordLength - 1), true);

        if (start.Y < 0 || start.BottomRight.Y > _textbox.ActualHeight)
            return;

        var wrapCorrectedStartRect = start.BottomRight.Y != end.BottomRight.Y ? new Rect(2, start.Y, start.Width, start.Height) : start;

        var highlightArea = Rect.Union(wrapCorrectedStartRect, end);

        drawingContext.DrawLine(_highlighterPen, highlightArea.BottomLeft, highlightArea.BottomRight);

        if (start.BottomRight.Y != end.BottomRight.Y)
            HighlightWrappedWord(drawingContext, characterIndex, end, wordLength);
    }

What I was hoping to achive was a Mouse Over effect for the line (without affecting the other lines), without having to invalidate the visual and redraw everything again. Please can anyone help on this?

You can override UIElement.OnMouseEnter and UIElement.OnMouseLeave on your adorner.
Because you can't modify the old DrawingContext you would have to invalidate the Adorner to add new content to the DrawingContex.
If the changes are not too complex, like adding new drawings, and you only want to change referenced resources like brushes an pens, you can define those resources as members and swap them in and out on UIElement.MoueseEnter and UIElement.MouseLeave. Note, this will only work for resources that implement Freezable e.g. like Pen and SolidColorBrush. This is because Freezable provides its own property changed mechanism which is used by the rendering engine to track property changes.
The following example shows how to enable the Adorner to change drawing resources dynamically:
private class TextBoxAdorner : Adorner
{
  private static readonly SolidColorBrush DefaultHighlightBrush;
  private static readonly SolidColorBrush MouseOverHighlightBrush;
  private static readonly Pen HighlighterPen;

  static TextBoxAdorner()
  {
    // Initialize from constructor so that we can freeze the resources
    // to enable a much better performance
    TextBoxAdorner.DefaultHighlightBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    TextBoxAdorner.DefaultHighlightBrush.Freeze();
    TextBoxAdorner.MouseOverHighlightBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    TextBoxAdorner.MouseOverHighlightBrush.Freeze();

    // Don't freeze the pen as we need to modify it
    // and the Freezable should report those changes to the rendering engine
    TextBoxAdorner.HighlighterPen = new Pen()
    {
      Brush = TextBoxAdorner.DefaultHighlightBrush,
      EndLineCap = PenLineCap.Square,
      StartLineCap = PenLineCap.Square
    };
  }

  public TextBoxAdorner(UIElement adornedElement) : base(adornedElement)
  {
    // IsHitTestVisible is TRUE by default. 
    // This line is added to emphasize that the property must be TRUE 
    // in order to enable the adorner to receive input events 
    this.IsHitTestVisible = true;
  }

  // Show mouse hover effects 
  protected override void OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnMouseEnter(e);

    // Set the mouse over effects.
    //
    // Because Pen is a freezable (unfrozen) 
    // any changes are noticed by the rendering engine
    TextBoxAdorner.HighlighterPen.Brush = TextBoxAdorner.MouseOverHighlightBrush;
  }

  // Hide mouse hover effects
  protected override void OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnMouseLeave(e);

    // Clear the mouse over effects.
    //
    // Because Pen is a freezable (unfrozen) 
    // any changes are noticed by the rendering engine
    TextBoxAdorner.HighlighterPen.Brush = TextBoxAdorner.DefaultHighlightBrush;
  }

  // Render the Adorner itself
  protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
  {
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);

    drawingContext.DrawLine(TextBoxAdorner.HighlighterPen, new Point(0, 0), new Point(200, 0));
  }
}


Thanks for the help. I guess the part that I am missing now is that there could be no buttons or there could be 50 buttons within the adorner depending how many unknown words there are present in the textbox

What do you mean? Are you asking "how to add "50" buttons to the adorner"? From a design perspective, your adorner shouldn't be too much involved. It should have the only responsibility to draw  some extra visuals o top of the TextBox. It should not process any text. You should have a spelchecking class that uses another text analyzer class to extract all the rendering information for the adorner (e.g. error positions and error span and error kind and error count etc.). Then from the TextBox.TextChanged event you pass this information to the adorner to update it.

Based on this information the adorner then adds e.g. 50 buttons dynamically. In this implementation your HighlightWord would process some e.g. TextInfo objects to know where to locate the drawings. No text processing in the adorner.

I guess I got a little confused by your solution as I dont currently draw any buttons within the adorner, I only draw a line under the unknown words (which is currently working). I was hoping to just recolour the line that is already drawn

I see. The button was just meant as an example to show you the possibilities and because drawings and visual have to be handled differently. The key takeaway should be turn the adorner into a visual host and add the objects as Visual children (either as DrawingVisual or Visual like a control) as this avoids to invalidate the adorner in order to force OnRender to be called (I understood that you want to avoid that). If you only want to draw a line then create the DrawingVisual like shown in this answer.

" I was hoping to just recolour the line that is already drawn" - This is some new information. Let me update the example.

Is _highlighterPen the color you want to change?
